# Using Solr for indexing and search with Mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, solr, lucene

Does anyone have any experience with this particular stack? I'm working on a web project that will eventually contain an extremely large amount of data and was trying to get Solr to play nicely with some simple Mongodb entries but I have found little to no information about it. I found this: http://blog.knuthaugen.no/2010/04/cooking-with-mongodb-and-solr.html which is mongodb + solr + php, but I'm struggling to see how I would use node similarly. Anybody have any insight? I'd greatly appreciate it. If this is a dumb thing to try to implement, feel free to let me know as well!

Found this library: https://github.com/tjgillies/node-lucene

Doesn't look like there is much documentation there but I'll give it a go.

Update:
So a quick fix (not ideal) that worked was to use a Perl module for lucene and then using the child process functionality in Node.js, I was able to insert and search for my data inside of lucene. So for a workaround, it does the trick.

Comment: +1 for interesting question about emerging technology

Comment: Have you considered ElasticSearch? It's highly popular and quite some people seem to use it in combination with MongoDB

Comment: I'll definitely look into that, thanks! Still, anyone have any experience with Solr, MongoDB, and Nodejs?

Comment: if you don't need a document structured DB here, and key-value is enough, maybe you can go with Riak and riak-js for node.js. But I'm also interested to hear some real experience about this stack, especially on production, including some benchmarks ;)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I'm trying to stay with a document structured DB. Once I find the solution (if there is one) I'll be sure to post benchmarks galore haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project looks promising: https://github.com/gsf/node-solr.  Not a whole lot of docs, but the tests are promisingly descriptive.

Then you would maybe do something like this in your mongoose schema:

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // this will be triggered when your mongoose schema object is saved
  // TODO add to a queue that sends the documents to SOLR in e.g. batches
  //      of 2000
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

I've been wanting to try mongo + SOLR + node but haven't started any coding yet.

Comment: Yeah that looks worth trying out. My patch job with Perl serves my need for now so hopefully with some free time in the future I'll try out this module instead.

Answer (score 4):

Probably as of Sep 2012, you would want to take a look at this.

https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client

Good documentations http://lbdremy.github.com/solr-node-client/ (though I didnt liked the web fonts used) but seems VERY promising.